# iAds not showing the banner

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app has been accepted for iAds advertising network, but after I download the app, I do not see the banner ad appears and I have to wait one week but still not see. I don't know if the app itself is faulty or not, here's the code I've used.

*ViewController.h*

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

*ViewController.m*

```
    #pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods
    -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [banner setAlpha:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [banner setAlpha:0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];    
    }
```

Comment: Just for your information, you shouldn't bother implementing iAd : the service will be closed by June 30 https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

Comment: @Niko No, it's not -- you've misinterpreted that announcement. (Don't worry, I did at first too!) What's being discontinued is the *iAd App Network*, which was used for placing advertisements for iOS applications through iAd. (That is, developers could use it to advertise their applications in other apps.)

Comment: ooooh you're so right! big misunderstanding from me!